# Constantly updated clock in zsh prompt?

Tags: zsh, prompt, zsh-zle

I know that I can exec a `date` command in my zsh prompt.
However, it shows the *old* time; to see the current time, I have to hit `<return>` and get a new prompt with the current time.

Is there a way to configure the zsh prompt to constantly update itself every second?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be .... unpleasant in a standard zsh prompt (or bash, or other shells).

I suggest you'd be better off using Gnu Screen.

Screen can have a status line which can show the time.
[Here's an example screenrc](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/screen.shtml) scroll down to "Red Hat Magazine A guide to GNU Screen" to see the sample (i'll reproduce that here) which will, when screen is run, show the current time in the lower right corner of the terminal:

~/.screenrc

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'

# Default screens
screen -t shell1        0
screen -t shell2        1
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Answer (score 70):

*Note: I wrote this answer for [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125825/zsh-update-prompt-with-current-time-when-a-command-is-started), but seeing how this question has more views I think reposting my answer here would be useful.*

This is in fact possible without resorting to strange hacks. I've got this in my .zshrc

```
RPROMPT='[%D{%L:%M:%S %p}]'

TMOUT=1

TRAPALRM() {
    zle reset-prompt
}
```

The TRAPALRM function gets called every TMOUT seconds (in this case 1), and here it performs a prompt refresh, and does so until a command starts execution (and it doesn't interfere with anything you type on the prompt before hitting enter).

Source: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg00944.html (It's from 2007!)

Comment: I can confirm that this actually works, despite how simple this appears.  All you really need is the `TMOUT=<SECONDS>; TRAPALRM () { zle reset-prompt }` part in your `$HOME/.zshrc` file and you're good to go.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I'd also recommend a longer timeout than 1 second. I used `TMOUT=30`. I noticed my shell hanging when it was every second.

Comment: Also, note that this might make copy-pasting more annoying.

Comment: Set the Trapalrm BEFORE tmout as on one of my Centos boxes executing a null TRAPALRM  cause a logout

Comment: Don't like that as I'm not able anymore to scroll back and read thinks carefully. When the prompt refreshs it wants to scroll to bottom

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, while it seems on some systems this causes inconvenience with copying and/or with scrolling, I'm using this technique without experiencing these issues.

Comment: Time formatting syntax in zsh, to save readers a search: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Date-and-time

Comment: This solution has a issue that:you can not scroll back in your terminal@nitarshan

Comment: @user13268019 Maybe it depends on which terminal?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a pleasant request to me.  If anything it makes more sense than showing the time when the prompt was displayed.

Fortunately [Peter Stephenson posted a technique](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg00946.html).  Try something like this in .zshrc:

```
PROMPT="[%T] %n@%M %~ %# "

schedprompt() {
  emulate -L zsh
  zmodload -i zsh/sched

  # Remove existing event, so that multiple calls to
  # "schedprompt" work OK.  (You could put one in precmd to push
  # the timer 30 seconds into the future, for example.)
  integer i=${"${(@)zsh_scheduled_events#*:*:}"[(I)schedprompt]}
  (( i )) && sched -$i

  # Test that zle is running before calling the widget (recommended
  # to avoid error messages).
  # Otherwise it updates on entry to zle, so there's no loss.
  zle && zle reset-prompt

  # This ensures we're not too far off the start of the minute
  sched +30 schedprompt
}

schedprompt
```

Comment: Just noticed the post asked for update every second.  I haven't tried it, but I'm guessing "sched +1 schedprompt" at the end of schedprompt() would do it.

Comment: Turns out the call to reset-prompt undoes any scrolling in the term window.  Makes it tough to scroll backwards and stay there for any length of time.

Comment: It's awesome! Not only it shows the current time but also it timestamps executed commands. Regarding the scrolling problem - you just need to turn off `scroll on output` feature of your terminal of choice.

Comment: @ArtemIce If you just need the command timestamp (like I did), you can use something like this: preexec () { echo -e "\033[1A`date +%H:%M:%S` " }