# zsh: update prompt with current time when a command is started

Tags: zsh, prompt, zsh-zle

I have a `zsh` prompt I rather like: it evaluates the current time in `precmd` and displays that on the right side of the prompt:

```
[Floatie:~] ^_^ 
cbowns%                      [9:28:31 on 2012-10-29]
```

However, this isn't *exactly* what I want: as you can see below, this time is actually the time the previous command exited, not the time the command was started:

```
[Floatie:~] ^_^ 
cbowns% date                           [9:28:26 on 2012-10-29]
Mon Oct 29 09:28:31 PDT 2012
[Floatie:~] ^_^ 
cbowns% date                           [9:28:31 on 2012-10-29]
Mon Oct 29 09:28:37 PDT 2012
[Floatie:~] ^_^ 
cbowns%                                [9:28:37 on 2012-10-29]
```

Is there a hook in `zsh` to run a command just *before* the shell starts a new command so I can update the prompt timestamp then? (I saw [Constantly updated clock in zsh prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187829/constantly-updated-clock-in-zsh-prompt), but I don't need it *constantly* updated, just updated when I hit enter.)

(The `^_^` is based on the previous command's return code. It shows `;_;` in red when there's a nonzero exit status.)

Comment: Share the the code for the happy/sad prompt?

Comment: @slashdottir Sure. I've changed it to some Unicode, but the concept still applies. `local smiley="%(?,%B%F{243}☆%f%b,%B%F{1}☃%f%b)"`, then that's interpolated into the PS1 var with `${smiley}`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had a struggle to make this:

It displays the date on the right side when the command has been executed.
It does not overwrite the command shown.
Warning: it may overwrite the current RPROMPT.

```
strlen () {
    FOO=$1
    local zero='%([BSUbfksu]|([FB]|){*})'
    LEN=${#${(S%%)FOO//$~zero/}}
    echo $LEN
}

# show right prompt with date ONLY when command is executed
preexec () {
    DATE=$( date +"[%H:%M:%S]" )
    local len_right=$( strlen "$DATE" )
    len_right=$(( $len_right+1 ))
    local right_start=$(($COLUMNS - $len_right))

    local len_cmd=$( strlen "$@" )
    local len_prompt=$(strlen "$PROMPT" )
    local len_left=$(($len_cmd+$len_prompt))

    RDATE="\033[${right_start}C ${DATE}"

    if [ $len_left -lt $right_start ]; then
        # command does not overwrite right prompt
        # ok to move up one line
        echo -e "\033[1A${RDATE}"
    else
        echo -e "${RDATE}"
    fi

}
```

Sources:

- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10564427/238913

Comment: This is a really awesome solution, but it chokes hard when I try to add colors into the mix.  It looks like the place to add the color setter is in the `echo` line, but if the color is set after the escape characters, i get extra `%{%}` characters beforehand.  And somehow, no matter where I try to reset the color scheme, i get those characters on the trailing end as well.

Comment: I recommend a couple of enhancements: 1) Add the date string in front of the time string... `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, and 2) Use a linefeed in front of `RDATE`... i.e. `RDATE="\n\033[${right_start}C ${DATE}"`

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you for contributing such a useful snippet!

Answer (score 45):

This is in fact possible without resorting to strange hacks. I've got this in my .zshrc

```
RPROMPT='[%D{%L:%M:%S %p}]'

TMOUT=1

TRAPALRM() {
    zle reset-prompt
}
```

The TRAPALRM function gets called every TMOUT seconds (in this case 1), and here it performs a prompt refresh, and does so until a command starts execution (and it doesn't interfere with anything you type on the prompt before hitting enter). I know you don't need it constantly refreshed but it still gets the job done without needing a line for itself!

Source: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg00944.html (It's from 2007!)

Comment: I would suggest enhancing this with a hack from there as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30456173/1091116

Comment: Also, note that this might make copy-pasting more annoying.

Comment: This is nice and simple, but setting TMOUT to 1 wreaks havoc on SSH sessions. If I don't run a command within 1 second of logging in, I get kicked out.

Comment: This fails to show the time for long lines, since zsh hides the rprompt when lines are too long

Comment: Having an updating time until the command is executed is quite nice. But with this solution, **arrow-up history stopped working** for me. Does anyone know a fix for that?

Comment: Thanks, Shevchuk, for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this still breaks my arrow-up history when initial letters have been entered: For example, entering `cd`, then pressing arrow up in order to browse through the previous `cd` commands. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 15):

You can remap the `Return` key to reset the prompt before accepting the line:

```
reset-prompt-and-accept-line() {
    zle reset-prompt
    zle accept-line
}

zle -N reset-prompt-and-accept-line

bindkey '^m' reset-prompt-and-accept-line
```

Comment: Ah, an interesting solution. Thank you!

Comment: I've just added this to my zsh theme before PROMPT and RPROMPT lines and it works really well. Thank you!

Comment: I like this approach a lot better, doesn't mess with word completion

Answer (score 14):

`zsh` will run the `preexec` function just before executing a line.  It would be simple to have that output the current time, a simple version would be just:

```
preexec() { date }
```

Modifying an existing prompt would be much more challenging.

Comment: Yeah, this is looking difficult, but `preexec()` is a good start. Thanks!

Comment: `zle reset-prompt` redraws the zsh prompt for you.

Comment: This works really well combined with [curses project](https://github.com/mccolin/curses) that echos out swear words. I set it up as following: `preexec() { /usr/bin/ruby /usr/local/curses/curse }` to great effect ;)

Answer (score 10):

Building off @vitaŭt-bajaryn's cool ZSH style [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33328293/751061):

I think overriding the accept-line function is probably the most idiomatic zsh solution:

```
function _reset-prompt-and-accept-line {
  zle reset-prompt
  zle .accept-line     # Note the . meaning the built-in accept-line.
}
zle -N accept-line _reset-prompt-and-accept-line
```

Comment: This doesn’t work when I do something like this ``C-r somestring RET``, i.e. run a line straight from reverse search without moving the cursor or modifying it.

Comment: I like this solution but it adds just a bit too much delay when pressing enter for me. Do you know if reset-prompt is intrinsically a bit slow or is it just my prompt that's slow to reset? I don't have much there, mostly just the time in RPROMPT (`%{$fg[white]%}[%*]%{$reset_color%}`) and git_prompt_info in PROMPT (`%{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%}% %{$reset_color%}:`)

Comment: If you want this to work with incremental search (C-r), add the following: `function _reset-prompt-and-accept-isearch {
    zle reset-prompt
    zle .zle-isearch-exit
}
zle -N zle-isearch-exit _reset-prompt-and-accept-isearch`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to write over the previous line, like this:

```
preexec () {
  DATE=`date +"%H:%M:%S on %Y-%m-%d"`
  C=$(($COLUMNS-24))
  echo -e "\033[1A\033[${C}C ${DATE} "
}
```