# Updating bash prompt

Tags: bash

Is there anyway to change the bash prompt to automatically update say when the time changes to reflect the time. So instead of something like it being `11:30` and the pressing enter 3 minutes later it then says `11:33` it would instead continuously update that prompt every minute to reflect the current time.

Comment: Not really. The prompt is simply printed to standard error, then `bash` waits until a command is executed to print the prompt again.

Comment: Sorry, but... no. The current bash version can only send the prompt once per read, and doesn't come back later to update a prompt it already emitted. Your best bet would be to implement this at the terminal emulator level. For example, I think GNU screen has a configuration setting for that.

Comment: I assume that there aren't really any other shell's that will allow me to do that either? Zsh or anything of the sort?

Comment: Most probably not, since, as others said, you need an emulator/or_something to capture the output and process it continuously, updating the time each and every second. You may be interested, as @JB. said, in using `GNU screen`, or `tmux` -- the later is a considerably *improved* version of `screen`.

Comment: I have a clock in my `tmux` status bar, which does update continuously. Keep in mind, however, your terminal emulator will interpret that as screen activity, if you use such a monitoring feature.

Comment: @legion See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187829/constantly-updated-clock-in-zsh-prompt for doing it in zsh.